# Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution."

Tags: upgrade, civicrm-home, core, ajax

This has come up a few times on SE but I've not found a working solution yet.

WP 6.4.3  / CiviCRM 5.68.1 - hosted on Cloudways / DigitalOcean (not sure that's relevant)

Upgrading to 5.69 and I got the Queue runner error - I figured it was a CiviCRM upgrade issue with the WP version, so rolled back and waited for 5.70

Still have the error (output below).

I've tried refreshing cache from the WP CiviCRM setting tab and I've tried deleting the entire of civicrm_cache from the WP_DB. Regular cron jobs are working fine.
I'm going to ask the Cloudways tech team to install cv so I can try a command line `cv upgrade:db` but I'm not optimistic at this point.

Any suggestions / solutions?

```
[Error: undefined]
Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution."

#0 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(93): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#1 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(38): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call()
#2 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(288): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#3 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#4 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#5 /home/***/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#6 /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#7 /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /home/***/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#10 {main}
```

Comment: CiviCRM 5.69+ has proper WP-CLI support - and WP-CLI might already be installed, if not then it's pretty easy https://wp-cli.org/#installing - so you could try `wp civicrm core update-db --vv` instead?

Comment: thanks - will try that this evening

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
wp civicrm core update-db --vv
```

> CiviCRM 5.69+ has proper WP-CLI support - and WP-CLI might already be
> installed, if not then it's pretty easy wp-cli.org/#installing - so
> you could try wp civicrm core update-db --vv instead?

Thanks @Christian

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you John.